# Upgraded to Ruby 2.1.1, what does this error mean about the interception gem when I use guard?

Tags: ruby, interceptor, guard

When I run `bundle exec guard` after upgrading to Ruby 2.1.1, I get this:

```
Frame number: 0/1
before_session hook failed: NotImplementedError: NotImplementedError
/home/eric/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/interception-0.4/lib/interception.rb:122:in `start'
(see _pry_.hooks.errors to debug)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

The officially released version of the interception gem you are using (0.4) checks for MRI Ruby 2.1 via the following method:

```
# lib/interception.rb 
def self.ruby_21?
  RUBY_VERSION == '2.1.0' && RUBY_ENGINE == 'ruby'
end
```

Obviously, this fails for Ruby 2.1.1

This is corrected in the master branch (https://github.com/ConradIrwin/interception), <strike>but the correction has not been released to RubyGems (as of 3/5/14)</strike>.

#### *Edit:*

As of 3/6/14, interception v0.5 has been released to RubyGems and fixes this issue. Verify the interception gem is not set to v0.4 or lower in your Gemfile, then run `bundle update interception`.